# Has anyone had any success using the Stack Profile tool in ArcGIS with a terrain dataset as a profile target?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst

Has anyone had any success using the [Stack Profile tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Stack_Profile/00q9000000mm000000/) in ArcGIS for Desktop [Advanced] with a terrain dataset as a profile target?

I have successfully used this tool with a raster dataset as a profile target but when I use a terrain dataset the tool fails. It writes out an empty table and returns

> **Error 999999**

with the message:

> **table not found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to esri tech support and this has now been logged as a bug.
NIM095101 Stack profile tool fails if the input profile target is specified as terrain dataset.

Comment: Just confirming for the record that this is working for me in 10.2.1